# replace method not working with global modifier

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, syntax

I am trying to replace a character in a string with multiple occurences in Javascript.

`String a1 = "There is a man over there";`

when i use `replace("e","x")`;

it will replace only the first occurrence of e.

So i am trying to use the g modifier like this `replace(/e/g,"x")`;

But i am facing with this error `Syntax error on tokens, Expression expected instead`

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Works for me: `"There is a man over there".replace(/e/g,'x')` Is yours different somehow?

Comment: `a1 = "There is a man over there"; a1.replace(/e/g,"x");` returns correctly "Thxrx is a man ovxr thxrx"

Comment: You've tagged your question `java` and also `javascript`. They're very different languages. Your `replace(/e/g, "x")` example is JavaScript. From the error, could it be you're trying to do that in Java code?

Comment: Guess i mixed up with <% %> and <script> tags, i am getting a replaceAll function as suggested below. Thnx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replace(/e/g,"x")` would be valid in **JavaScript** but not in **Java**. For Java just use the following:

```
String a1 = "There is a man over there";
String replaced = a1.replaceAll("e", "x"); // "Thxrx is a man ovxr thxrx"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are mixing Java and Javascript which have absolutely nothing to do with each other.

Since you said you are trying in Javascript, do this:

```
var a1 = "There is a man over there";  // not String a1...
a1.replace(/e/g, 'x');
```